# filewatcher watch several files but handle them differently

Tags: c#, filesystemwatcher

I need to watch several file at different time and sometimes at the same time.

I am using this as a test:

```
namespace FilewatcherTest
{
  public partial class Form1 : Form
  {
    private System.IO.FileSystemWatcher FSWatcherTest;

    public Form1()
    {
      InitializeComponent();

      FSWatcherTest = new FileSystemWatcher();
      EventHandling();
      FSWatcherTest.Path = @"d:\tmp";
      FSWatcherTest.Filter = "file.txt";
      // Begin watching.
      FSWatcherTest.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    }

    protected void EventHandling()
    {
      FSWatcherTest.Changed += FSWatcherTest_Changed;
      FSWatcherTest.Deleted += FSWatcherTest_Deleted;
      FSWatcherTest.Renamed += FSWatcherTest_Renamed;
      FSWatcherTest.Created += FSWatcherTest_Created;
    }

    private void FSWatcherTest_Changed(object sender, System.IO.FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
      WriteToLog("File Changed");
    }

    private void FSWatcherTest_Created(object sender, System.IO.FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
      WriteToLog("File Created");
    }

    private void FSWatcherTest_Deleted(object sender, System.IO.FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
      WriteToLog("File Deleted");          
    }

    private void FSWatcherTest_Renamed(object sender, System.IO.RenamedEventArgs e)
    {
      WriteToLog("File Renamed");
    }

    private void WriteToLog(string message)
    {
      using (var sw = new StreamWriter(@"d:\tmp\service.log", true))
      {
        sw.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} {1}", DateTime.Now,message));
      }

    }

  }
}
```

Of course I'll change the hardcoded paths once I have something in place since this is going into a service I created.

My question is, can I use the same file watcher or should I use a unique one for each file?

If I use the same one, how do I know which file is raising the event?

Thanks!!

**EDIT
Sorry I haven't used filesystemwatcher before and didn't know it mattered but the files will be in different directories and not of the same file type.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> can I use the same file watcher or should I use a unique one for each file?

In your case, I don't think there is a reason to create a new instance of FileSystemWatcher for every file you're watching. Yes, you can use the same one. You can use a filter such as "*.txt" or whatever you need to watch a set of files...

> If I use the same one, how do I know which file is raising the event?

The [`FileSystemEventArgs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/40yayd7f.aspx) has a `Name` property which returns the name of the file that triggered the event. 
So for example:

```
private void FSWatcherTest_Created(object sender, System.IO.FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
   string fileName = e.Name; 
   WriteToLog("File Created: " + fileName);
}
```

Comment: the files will have different names completely and in different locations, how would I add them individually as I need to?

Comment: That's up to you. Do they have the same suffix for instance? You can also choose to watch the entire directory and only do something if the file that triggered the event is one of your files

Comment: sry I edited it before after you answered they will be in different directories

Comment: Again, totally depends on what exactly you configuration is. If it helps, you can use the `IncludeSubdirectories` property which will allow to monitor subdirectories too. If the files are in totally different locations You'll have to create multiple FileSystemWatcher s but you can set the same callback methods for all of them

Comment: k that's what I was wanting to know tyvm